# Django Newbe: What is the best way to go about creating groups?

Tags: django

I am trying to allow users to create their own groups, let other users(members) join the group. I would like to have some guidance on how to do this, any links or resources would be helpful. I have just deleted my first attempt, starting again. I will post some of my code later. In my last attempt I kept on getting the Error 404: no user matches the query. I already have my profiles app and UserLogin by email app built.

UPDATE:

Thanks all but I have figured it out, I used the pinax groups app to guide me and just customised certain areas.

Comment: your question is unclear. If you talk about "system" permission groups you may want to use the django.contrib.auth.models.Group model but it may be a bad answer.

If you have to manage right not to tables but to specific rows you may probably want to have your own 'group' model.

Groups are usually managed with generated admin.

Do you really want to manage group or a simple manytomany relation?

Comment: Thanks for replying, i apologise for my vague question. It seems like will have to create a group table with a many2many relation with members. I want the users to create a group that other users can join i.e become members of. I am going to take a look at django.contrib.auth.models.Group, i never knew that. I am also going through the Pinax Basic_Groups source code for an idea.

Comment: you mean a bit like mailing lists? one can create mailing list and everybody can join? if yes you dont need generic groups, just a manytomany field on the content channel.

Comment: Look at http://djangopackages.com. There's probably an app that does exactly what you want (whatever it is)

Comment: Thanks Natan, i am really trying to learn how to do it on my own so that i can increase my development skills, also i did check and the closest i came to a group package was Pinax and i am working through it now.